# Infamous: Invalid index n for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, lucene.net

This exception:

Invalid index n for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=

Usually points at duplicate mapping information (see Stack Overflow + Google). I am pretty sure I have none. Are there any other reasons for it?

I seem to have identified the problem. I introduced this:

```
[DocumentId]
public virtual int GI
{
    get { return base.Id; }
    protected set { base.Id = value; }
}
```

To use search via lucene.net. This seems to interfere with FNH! What are my options here?

PS:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.RangeCheck(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.Int32Type.Set(IDbCommand rs, Object value, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
   at SharpArch.Data.NHibernate.DbContext.CommitChanges()
   at Updater1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\bla\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Bla\Updater1\Program.cs:line 97
```

PPS:

```
public class MappedSequenceMap : IAutoMappingOverride<MappedSequence>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<MappedSequence> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "GI").GeneratedBy.Assigned();

            mapping.Map(x => x.Affiliation).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.Gene).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.OriginalIsolationCountry).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.OriginalAffiliation).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.PMIDs).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.Product).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.Fasta).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.Note).Length(10000);
            mapping.Map(x => x.Strain).Length(10000);

            mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.PubmedPublications).Table("SequencesPubmedPublications");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I said that I googled and searched SO (see question)!!! There is no HQL involved as it is a simple Save() of an entity via a s#arp repository.

Comment: I would re-post the full exception (exception.ToString()) and post the relevant mapping just to be sure.

Comment: Need to see the full mapping for the entity in question

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The answer is either:-

a) you have a duplicate property mapped in the same class

b) It is possible if you are exposing a foreign-key as well as using a `<many-to-one ...` to the related entity in the mapping file. If this is the case add  `insert="false" and update="false"` to the foreign key property and run again.

To verify this, as you are using fluent and automapping, you need to look at the XML mappings. See this [link][2] and use `ExportTo(..)` method. Once you have done this look at the `XML` and see if you have any duplicate properties OR even duplicate mapping files.

In you case, you have two references to column `GI`:

```
<id name="Id" ...>
  <column name="GI" />
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>

<property name="GI" ...>
  <column name="GI" />
</property>
```

I take it you can't set the annotation `[DocumentId]` on the `Id` class property. I think you may need to abandon auto mapping for this class and configure via fluent manually!

Comment: @bartoszKP due to your editing this does not read very well at all now :)

Comment: Sorry, for making your post confusing. My intent was to make it a complete answer without any historical noise. It was helpful for me, but it was a bit hard to navigate through all the PPSes ;) How is it now? Of course feel free to improve the post even more, especially if I'm still missing what you wanted to say in the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

With full credit to @Rippo, the equivalent answer in Fluent NHibernate which helped me is:

For the classes:

```
public class User
{
   public virtual Department {get; set;}
}

public class Department
{
   public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
}
```

If you have the following mapping for the `User` entity:

```
//Problem mapping
Map(x => x.DepartmentId)          
References(x => x.Department)
   .Column("Id")
   .ForeignKey("DepartmentId")
   .Fetch.Join();
```

The following is one of the possible solutions (due to double mapping in the `one-to-many`part - `one-Department-to-many-Users`):

```
// !Solution
Map(x => x.DepartmentId)          
References(x => x.Department)
   .Column("Id")
   .ForeignKey("DepartmentId")
   .Fetch.Join()
   .Not.Insert()   // <- added this
   .Not.Update();  // <- and this
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error where in my Fluent IAutoMappingOverride class I had a mapping.IgnoreProperty(p => Property) where Property was only a getter.  I removed the IgnoreMap statement and it fixed it.  This is with NH 3.3.1.4.  Probably doesn't relate to your issue, but hopefully this will help someone else.